# How to sort HQL with custom order?

Tags: hibernate, sorting, jpa, hql

I need to sort a list of entity, with the following rules:

XS, S, M, L, XL, 2XL...

The standard order by in HQL that I know can only sort by alphabetical and numerical. Is the above order possible?

My current code:

```
SELECT S FROM Shirt S ORDER BY S.size;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below query :

```
 SELECT S FROM Shirt S ORDER BY (CASE S.size WHEN 'XS' THEN 1
    WHEN 'S' THEN 2
    WHEN 'M' THEN 3
    WHEN 'L' THEN 4
    WHEN 'XL' THEN 5
    WHEN '2XL' THEN 6
    END);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have right model your POJO this is a simple operation.

I suppose you have:

Class `Shirt`

with a property `DressSize dressSize`

and a Class `DressSize`

with these properties:

```
String description
int orderNum
```

So your query will become:

```
SELECT S FROM Shirt S ORDER BY S.dressSize.orderNum
```

Comment: That is neat, but too bad it is not code in this way. It is just a Shirt class with String size property.

Comment: @VHanded: Dear, you must use an object as DressSize and no a Strnig property. So you have only an alphabetical order. You can use CASE WHEN in ORDER BY but can create problem)